# Unable to set default values for SynPS/2 Synaptic

Tags: touchpad, 16.10, synaptics, xinput

Today i noticed that my trackpad was not responding to click events, click and drag and two finger scrolling. (I mostly use a mouse, so i can't assure you, when did it all started)

I looked up and found that my kernel identifies my touchpad (SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad), so it is not Kernel Problem.

Then, I checked for all Input Devices by executing `xinput list` and I found my TouchPad. Then i looked up for its properties and found that all above mentioned actions were disabled. Here is what is default properities :

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (143):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (296): 0
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (297): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (298):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (299):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (300):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (301):   0
libinput Accel Speed (279): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (280): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (284):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (285):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (263): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (264):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (265):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (286): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (287): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   1, 0, 0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (302):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (303):    1
Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event6"
Device Product ID (267):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (295):   <no items>
libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (268):    1
```

Clearly As You can see **Tapping is not enabled** .
I tried setting it up manually, and i was able to enable the Tappings by executing `xinput set-prop "12" "296" "1"` and my Trackpad now Responds to Tappings.

But As You know, it only for Particular session, and i will have to again set it manually everytime i boot. But i found there is *property id 297* which says default. I tried setting this Manually by

`sudo xinput set-prop "12" "297" "1"`

but ended up with this.

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)


Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

I tried it being super user also, but no luck.

Please, I do not want to set a script which will auto execute after every boot/start, i want to enable it simply.

Hope You Could help me...

Comment: It's interesting that your device appears to be a Synaptics touchpad, but the driver is `libinput`. Is the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default value in your libinput config file located at

> /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

(mine is actually 90-libinput.conf. anyways, something like this.)

Just add

```
Option "Tapping" "True"
```

For me, the complete entry is:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
EndSection
```

See more at:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput

https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput