# Touchpad can't be configured properly

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 18.04, synaptics

I'm using HP 15-ba077cl laptop in 18.04, and can't configure the touchpad.

Symptoms:

1. Can't tap with the touchpad (physical button and two-finger scrolling works, though).
2. On `gnome-control-center`, it shows the configuration entry for touchpads, but I can't either configure normal and inverted scroll. On `unity-control-center`, it doesn't show at all.
   Screenshot for [GNOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj9cc.png) and
   [Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2y2c.png).
3. This issue doesn't appear on 16.04.

Here is the dump of `xinput list`:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD: HP TrueVision           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Dump of `xinput list-props 13`:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (292): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (293): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (294):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (295):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (296):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (297):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (298):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (299):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (274):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (275):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (300):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (301):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (276):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (277):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (278):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (283): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (284): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (288): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (289): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (259): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (260):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (261):    0, 0
    Device Node (262):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (263):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (290):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (291):   1
```

How do I resolve this issue so I can configure it?

Comment: Dumped the output. I think I figured out the problem, but don't know how to resolve it. Also, the link provided doesn't help me. Perhaps, my custom mouse accel setting screws it up?

Comment: It's interesting that your device appears to be a Synaptics touchpad, but the driver is `libinput`. Is the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` installed?

Comment: Nope. So that's the reason why it's not detected... @xiota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `xinput list-props` it says:

```
libinput Tapping Enabled (292): 0
```

which I'm pretty sure means tapping is configured as disabled.

Therefore - a possible solution to Symptom 1 is to run:

```
xinput set-prop 13 292 1
```

This should set the property `Tapping Enabled (292)` to a value of `1` (Enabled).

This may only enable it for your current session though. So to make the change permenant - I think you would need to edit your configuration within `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` as described here:
[Unable to set default values for SynPS/2 Synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903206/unable-to-set-default-values-for-synps-2-synaptic)

Comment: Using more `xinput` entry allows me to do so, like natural scrolling and such. But still, it can't be configured via GUI, which worries me a lot...

Comment: *How do I resolve this issue so I can configure it?* I think the answer is already helping me to resolve the issue. Just... needs more explanation on why it can't be configured via GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Your device appears to be a Synaptics touchpad, but the driver shown in the `xinput` output is `libinput`.  Ubuntu 18.04 uses X.org by default.  Probably the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is not installed.  If this is the case, you might want to install it to see if it addresses your problems with the GUI.

```
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Caveat: The `synaptics` driver appears to not support "Natural Scrolling".  So you might prefer to stick with the `libinput` driver.

Comment: It addresses the issue via GUI.